# Haskell recursive function size that returns the number of elements in a set

Tags: function, haskell, recursion, size

Write a recursive function size in haskell that returns the number of elements in a set. Do not use the library function **length.**

```
size ::  Set a -> Int
```

This is what i did so far. Does it look right or am i misunderstanding what the question is asking? Thanks

```
  size ::  Set a -> Int
  size [] = 1
  size (_:xs) = 1  + size xs
```

Comment: There's a little bit of context missing from your question, namely the definition of `Set`. If it's declared as `type Set = []` then your code is _almost_ correct. You just need to adjust the base case - an empty set should have a size of 0. (A couple of suggestions of things to think about as an exercise: How would you make this function tail recursive? Would that be a good idea for performance? Can this function be expressed using a fold?)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, `size` is declared as you mentioned `type Set a = [a]`. I'll look into your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot one important part: the fact that the empty list `[]` has size `0`, so:

```
size ::  Set a -> Int
size [] = 0                 -- zero
size (_:xs) = 1  + size xs
```

Besides code however it is important to be able to explain your code. The first clause can be explained like:

> "The size of an empty list is zero (0)".

The recursive clause on the other hand can be explained as:

> The size of the non-empty list is the same as one plus the size of a set minus one element (the head).

Note that here, we make the assumption that the type `Set a` is the same as `[a]`. This however means that we can have sets with duplicate entries. In case we do not want that, we should use a uniqueness filter. We can use `nub :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]` for that, or we can implement it in our `size` function:

```
size :: Set a -> Int
size = size' []
    where size' _ [] = 0
          size' l (x:xs) | elem x l = size' l xs
                         | otherwise = 1 + size' (x:l) xs
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution using higher-order functions:

```
size :: Set a -> Int
size = sum . fmap (const 1)
```

This works because `Set` is an instance of `Foldable` and can be made an instance of `Functor`.